# Regex to find an ID code within an email subject line

Tags: c#, .net, regex

We are implementing a feature in our web application that reads email subjects and checks the subject for a certain string containing an ID so that we can match incoming emails to projects in our application.

A subject may look like this: Stand-by vessel requirement 07.03.2013 [FIX:1012]

I need to identify the string in square brackets and pull out just the number from it: '1012'

So far i have come up with this:

```
\[[a-z]{5}:[0-9]{4}\]\Z
```

But this only matches the whole string : [FIX:1012]

Where do i go from here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use look-behind and look-ahead:**

```
(?<=\[[a-z]{5}:)[0-9]{4}(?=\]\Z)
```

`?<=` is look-behind and `?=` is look-ahead.

**Using groups:**

Just putting it in brackets to put it in the first group:

```
\[[a-z]{5}:([0-9]{4})\]\Z
```

To use groups would be something like (untested):

```
Match match = regex.Match(input);
if (match.Success)
{
    string v = match.Groups[1].Value;
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", v);
}
```

[Reference](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-groups).

**Also:**

I'm not really sure how `[a-z]{5}` works for your string (this is only exactly 5 lower-case characters).

Comment: Your correct it should be [a-z]{3}. I added the language tags also. [a-z] seems to match uppercase too in .NET

Comment: ok i tweaked your answer a bit and came up with this, which seems to work: \[FIX:([0-9]{4})\]

Answer (score 0):

Here is your regex code :

```
     [0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?+(:*?])
```

This will give you 1012 number which is between " : "  " ] "